# Javascript Canvas drawing an octagon

Tags: javascript, function, canvas

Working on Javascript Canvas drawing an octagon and I have this function and code, but its not working for some reason. Any ideas?

```
function drawMe()
{   
var numberOfSides = 8;
    size = 10;
    Xcenter = 100;
    Ycenter = 100;

cxt.beginPath();
cxt.moveTo (Xcenter +  size * Math.cos(0), Ycenter +  size *  Math.sin(0));          

for (var i = 1; i <= numberOfSides; i += 1) 
{
    cxt.lineTo (Xcenter + size * Math.cos(i * 2 * Math.PI / numberOfSides), Ycenter + size * Math.sin(i * 2 * Math.PI / numberOfSides));
}

cxt.strokeStyle = "#000000";
cxt.lineWidth = 1;
cxt.stroke();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code will successfully draw a hexagon (I assume you will change the 6 to an 8) as long as cxt is a valid reference to a canvas context.

If it's not drawing a hexagon, be sure you have a valid reference to a context.

Example code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="css/reset.css" /> <!-- reset css -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<style>
    body{ background-color: ivory; }
    canvas{border:1px solid red;}
</style>
<script>
$(function(){

    var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
    var cxt=canvas.getContext("2d");

    var numberOfSides = 6;
        size = 10;
        Xcenter = 100;
        Ycenter = 100;

    cxt.beginPath();
    cxt.moveTo (Xcenter +  size * Math.cos(0), Ycenter +  size *  Math.sin(0));          

    for (var i = 1; i <= numberOfSides; i += 1) 
    {
        cxt.lineTo (Xcenter + size * Math.cos(i * 2 * Math.PI / numberOfSides), Ycenter + size * Math.sin(i * 2 * Math.PI / numberOfSides));
    }

    cxt.strokeStyle = "#000000";
    cxt.lineWidth = 1;
    cxt.stroke();

}); // end $(function(){});
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <canvas id="canvas" width=300 height=300></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Chuckle, quite right...the OP's code has leaked globals!  Myself, I always semi-colon all initialized variables and comma separate all declared but uninitialized vars.

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
<script>
    var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    ctx.strokeStyle = "#000000";
    ctx.lineWidth = 1;
    function drawMe()
    {   
        var numberOfSides = 8,
        size = 10,
        Xcenter = 100,
        Ycenter = 100;
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.moveTo (Xcenter +  size * Math.cos(0), Ycenter +  size *  Math.sin(0));          
        for (var i = 1; i <= numberOfSides; i += 1) 
        {
            ctx.lineTo (Xcenter + size * Math.cos(i * 2 * Math.PI / numberOfSides), Ycenter + size * Math.sin(i * 2 * Math.PI / numberOfSides));
        }
        ctx.stroke();
    }
    drawMe();
</script>
</body>
</html>
```